# Close the main thread

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am doing restoration process through smo. After sucessful restoration i enable my database back
        currentDb.SetOnline();

Problem is the database instance doesnt work after that. the instance failed to connect. So i thought y not i shutdown my application.

```
    Application.Exit();
```

But writing the above code doesnt exist my app rather then i got exception. Details are

`enter code here`System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

```
Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="VitoProject"
  StackTrace:
       at VitoProject.backAndRestore.restoreDatabase_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\WorkSpace\VitoProject\VitoProject\backAndRestore.cs:line 176
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at VitoProject.Program.Main() in C:\WorkSpace\VitoProject\VitoProject\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be not the best solution, but if you're trying to exit your application and something is getting hung, you may want to try;

```
Environment.Exit(1);
```

Comment: note: just found out passing 1 is if you're expecting errors. a cleaner method is to pass 0.